# Slider with max value greater than 2147483647 in wxPython Phoenix?

Tags: python, slider, wxpython, limit

Basically, the `wx.Slider` widget from wxPython Phoenix cannot go further than `2147483647`.

Indeed,

```
slider = wx.Slider( parent   = parent,
                    value    = 10,
                    minValue = 0,
                    maxValue = 2147483647 )
print slider.GetMax()
```

Outputs :

> 2147483647

Whereas,

```
slider = wx.Slider( parent   = parent,
                    value    = 10,
                    minValue = 0,
                    maxValue = 2147483648 )
print slider.GetMax()
```

Outputs :

> (program.py:5403): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_range_set_range: assertion
>   'min < max' failed
>   0

I need to use bigger values with that widget. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered just dividing your values by an appropriate divisor.

Edit:
There are times when you simply have to be pragmatic. You cannot possibly display or use a slider with a length of 2 billion. Whether it is automatically generated or not, it is simpler to make the slider utilise values between 0% and 100%, you can always manipulate the `tooltip` to display a value if that is essential but even then the accuracy of a given position when using such a massive number would in my opinion, be so inaccurate as to be meaningless.

Comment: Yes but it cannot work as the sliders are automatically generated and that would be too much of a case by case division, to make sense.

Comment: That is a nice approach but unfortunately the values have to be accurately settable. A high value might only be used once but it has to be able to be set with precision. Hence I think I will add an editable `wx.TextCtrl` on the right of the slider so the value will be accurately settable and the `wx.SpinCtrl` will be used to display the value within the range and set it approximately.

Comment: Be aware that `wx.SpinCtrl` has the same size limitation (2147483647)

Comment: The problem appears to be related to the C limits.h file, which specifies the maximum/minimum size of an integer, whereas sys.maxint on a 64bit machine is 9223372036854775807, the limits.h specifies 2147483647. I have no idea why!

Comment: Oops I meant `wx.Slider`. Yes I saw that for the `wx.SpinCtrl` too. I assume it is implemented with a `int` 32 bits (as 2147483647 is the max positive value for a `signed int32`) for compatibility reason with 32 bits machine. And there is `wx.SpinCtrlDouble` for biggest values and floating point.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's a 32 bit machine? 
2147483647 (or 2^31-1 (since we're counting from 0)) is the biggest integer a 32 bit machine can handle

Comment: 64-bit machine. Other widgets can go to bigger values, only this one seems to have a limitation of some kind. Actually, some of those have multiple versions (i.e. `wx.SpinCtrl` and `wx.SpinCtrlDouble`).

Comment: I assume wxPython Phoenix limits it then